# moodle redirect to "Incorrect access detected"

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, moodle

If I enter the url of moodle into my browser I get the redirect page saying:

> Incorrect access detected, this server may be accessed only through
>   "http://lms.example.ir/moodle" address, sorry. Please notify server
>   administrator.

But the automatic redirect keeps trying to load it.

-I put in  `config.php` file

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://lms.example.ir/moodle';
```

-I put this code in `.htaccess`

```
#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lms.example\.ir [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lms.example.ir/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I installed moodle 1.9.19+ and It worked like a charm with FQDN !! but moodle 2.8 show me redirect message as I said . I changed wwwroot 'http://lms.example.ir/moodle' to 'http://ADDRESSIP/moodle' and just load home page without theme and image ... any suggestion?

Comment: I found the problem is the value of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . it return ip address instead of domain name . How can I solve this?

Comment: Is this something to do with the settings in your web server configuration?  Does the web server software know itself only by IP address instead of proper server name?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I'll check it.

Answer (score 1):

you should use %{SERVER_NAME} instead of %{HTTP_HOST} in your .htaccess file.